# Increase font of y and x axis labels (not the y and x axis title)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data frame that I want to plot, the dataframe (the x variable in the below code) looks like this:

```
Name1 4
Name2 4
Name3 4
Name4 4
Name5 4
Name6 4
Name7 4
Name8 5
Name9 5
Name10 6
Name11 6
Name12 7
Name13 9
Name14 9
Name15 10
Name16 10
Name17 27
```

I want to plot the data on a barplot, the code is:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

fam_dict = {}
df = pd.read_csv(open(sys.argv[1]),header=0,sep='\t')
x = df['family_name'].str.capitalize().value_counts(ascending=True)[-17:]


x.plot(kind='barh')
ax = x.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(30, 20), color='#86bf91', zorder=2, width=0.85)

# Despine
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

# Switch off ticks
ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

# Draw vertical axis lines
vals = ax.get_xticks()
for tick in vals:
    ax.axvline(x=tick, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, color='#eeeeee', zorder=1)

# Set x-axis label
ax.set_xlabel("Number of entries", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=18)

# Set y-axis label
ax.set_ylabel("Name", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=18)

# Format y-axis label
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,g}'))


ax.figure.savefig('test_top.png',format='png')
```

I want to do two things:

1. Change the font size of the x and y-axis labels, i.e. not the y axis/x axis title (which i know how to do), but the actual labels (i.e. here, Name1 -> Name17, and the number 4->27).
2. Add an actual line running on the a axis. I've added a screenshot to show what I mean, how would I draw an actual line running along the x axis (whereas here it just says 5,10,15, but there's no actual line running along the bottom of the graph).

Can someone show me how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change font size of tick labels:

```
    for tl in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        tl.set_fontsize(3)       
    for tl in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
        tl.set_fontsize(30)
```

2. Add an actual line running on the a axis:

IIUC you want to see the axis line: just don't set the spine's visibility to `False`, i.e. comment out these lines:

```
#ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
#ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
```

(or set the visibility to `True`)